# problem with iterating through the JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, iterator

In the code below, I tried iterating over the JSON object string. However, I do not get the desired output. My output on the webpage looks something like:-

+item.temperature++item.temperature++item.temperature++item.temperature+

The alert that outputs the temperature works well. The part where I try accessing the value by iterating through the JSON object string doesn't seem to work. Could some one help me out with fixing this?

**Code**

```
<body>
    <script>
    $.getJSON('http://ws.geonames.org/weatherJSON?north=90&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2',
      function(data) {
        $.each(data.weatherObservations, function(i, item) {
          $("body").append("+item.temperature+");
          if (-i == 3-) return false;
        });
        alert(data.weatherObservations[0].temperature);
      });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use quotes within `$("body").append("+item.temperature+");` in the `.append()` part.

should be

```
$(document.body).append(item.temperature);
```

Writting that expression with quotes like you did, just adds a `string` over and over. Java//Ecmascript interpretates anything withing quotes as a string literal.

Notice that I also replaced `"body"` with `document.body`. That has mostly performance // access reasons, so better karma.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is iterating through, but you're appending "+item.temperature+", don't you want to do something like

```
$("body").append("Temp is " + item.temperature);
```

or

```
$("body").append(item.temperature);
```

Answer (score 0):

`"+item.temperature+"` means a string which is `"+item.temperature+"`

`"pre" + item.temperature + "post"` will concatenate the variable to the strings.

```
$.getJSON('http://ws.geonames.org/weatherJSON?north=90&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2', 
  function (data) {
    $.each(data.weatherObservations, function (i, item) {
        $("body").append(item.temperature + ",");
        if (i == 3) return false;
    });
    alert(data.weatherObservations[0].temperature);
});
```